# Regex match repeatation punctuation in java

Tags: java, regex

I have some punctuation `[] punctuation = {'.', ',' , '!', '?'};`. And I want create a regex that can match the word that was combined from those punctuations.

For example some string I want to find: `"....???"`, `"!!!!!......"`, `"??.....!"`, so on.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: And what about, say, `!!??...,,,`?

Comment: Do you only need those characters or any punctuation? Do you need to match punctuation sequences of a specific minimum length or from 1 to any length?

Comment: @Mena I just need those punctuation. Thank you.

Comment: @HoaVu ok and do you need a specific minimum size? Or just _any_ match of punctuation from 1 character up?

Comment: @Mena I just need any match from those punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should match and group all the symbols written between `[]`:

```
([.,!?]+)
```

Tested it with

```
??..,..!fsdgsdfgsdfgsdfg
```

And output was

```
??..,..!
```

---

Also tested with this:

```java
String s = "??.....!fsdgsdfgsdfgsdfg?.,!0000a";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([.,!?]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

And output was

```
??.....!
?.,!
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) with the posix regex for "punctuation":

```
str.matches("\\p{Punct}+");
```

FYI according to the [`Pattern` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), `\p{Punct}` is one of

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

Also, The `^` and `$` aren't needed in the expression either, because `matches()` must matche the *whole* input to return true, so start and end are implied.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a Unicode category for punctuation and a `while` loop to match your input, as such:

```
String test = "!...abcd??...!!efgh....!!??abc!";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Punct}{2,}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Output:

```
!...
??...!!
....!!??
```

Note: this has the advantage of matching *any* punctuation character sequence **larger than 1 character** (hence, the last "!" is not matched *by design*). To decide the minimum length of the punctuation sequence, just play with the *{2,}* part of the `Pattern`.

Comment: 1. The OP is specifying which characters he wants to match, so the **all** punctuation matching isn't needed, 2. This regex misses the last `!`, 3. The OP never told about matching something larger than 2 characters

Comment: @BackSlash Yes it is missing the last "!" by design, because I assume the OP wants sequences longer than 2 characters. I also assume the OP's example of characters to match is not exhaustive. **Edit** I asked for details in the question comments.